# socket.io - Detect an emit from any client in a namespace on the server side?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Given the namespace object on server side, how would you detect when any client emits a message?

Comment: Last I checked, socket.io does not have a supported way to do that.  You would have to listen for all possible messages the client can send in order to monitor them.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I solved the problem by using a for loop to loop over all the connected client socket objects and adding an eventlistener on the server side to listen for any emitted events.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using a for loop to loop over all the connected client socket objects and adding an eventlistener on the server side to listen for any emitted events.

**Server Side:**

```
for(var key in clientList){
    clientList[key].on('event', function(){
        console.log("event occured")
    })
}
```

Comment: This type of solution does a one time addition of event handlers to the current set of sockets.  Usually, you would just add this event listener in the `connect` event whenever anyone connects and it would just always be there.  You can then decide when you want to pay attention to the event based on state.